# What does man page for pmap look like on 12.04?

Tags: manpage

I was trying to find out information about pmap this morning, and ran `man pmap`... the man page gives me the options for launching pmap, but tells me *nothing* about how to interpret what I see on the screen when I've run the program. I would like to report this as a bug in Launchpad, but I want to know if this has been fixed in a newer version of Ubuntu.

I'm running 10.04. Here's what I get:

```
NAME
       pmap - report memory map of a process

SYNOPSIS
       pmap [-x|-d] [-q] pid  ...
       pmap -V

DESCRIPTION 
       The pmap command reports the memory map of a process or processes.

GENERAL OPTIONS        
       -x   extended       Show the extended format.
       -d   device         Show the device format.
       -q   quiet          Do not display some header/footer lines.
       -V   show version   Displays version of program.

SEE ALSO
       ps(1), pgrep(1)

STANDARDS
       No  standards apply, but pmap looks an awful lot like a SunOS com‐
       mand.

AUTHOR
       Albert Cahalan <albert@users.sf.net> wrote pmap in  2002,  and  is
       the  current  maintainer of the procps collection. Please send bug
       reports to <procps-feedback@lists.sf.net>.

Linux                        October 26, 2002                     PMAP(1)
```

Can someone run this on a more modern Ubuntu, and see if the man pages have been updated in the last couple of years? (I'm guessing not... the previous revision was in 2002, but I still like to cover my bases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All manpages are also hosted in browser friendly html on the Ubuntu servers. You can access them from:

#### [Ubuntu Manpage Repository](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/)

There also is a custom search field to find specific manpages. This will eventually lead you to the [manpage for pmap in 12.04 LTS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pmap.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have 12.04. Here is the man page, it seems the same:

```
PMAP(1)                                                                                                   Linux User's Manual                                                                                                   PMAP(1)



NAME
       pmap - report memory map of a process


SYNOPSIS
       pmap [-x|-d] [-q] pid  ...
       pmap -V


DESCRIPTION
       The pmap command reports the memory map of a process or processes.


GENERAL OPTIONS
       -x   extended       Show the extended format.
       -d   device         Show the device format.
       -q   quiet          Do not display some header/footer lines.
       -V   show version   Displays version of program.


SEE ALSO
       ps(1), pgrep(1)


STANDARDS
       No standards apply, but pmap looks an awful lot like a SunOS command.


AUTHOR
       Albert Cahalan <albert@users.sf.net> wrote pmap in 2002, and is the current maintainer of the procps collection. Please send bug reports to <procps-feedback@lists.sf.net>.



Linux                                                                                                       October 26, 2002                                                                                                    PMAP(1)
```